How to set a chat menu button for telegram bot using Rust crate 'Teloxide'
I'm trying to add a menu button for my webapp to my telegram bot using teloxide crate.
I have found MenuButton enum and set_chat_menu_button(&self) method,
but don't understand how to use them?

Solution:

add url crate to Cargo.toml
set the menu button for private chat in response to the /start command:

bot.set_chat_menu_button()
.chat_id(msg.chat.id)
.menu_button(MenuButton::WebApp {
  text: "My button".to_owned(),
  web_app: WebAppInfo {
    url: Url::parse("https://duckduckgo.com").unwrap(),
  },
}).await?;

